# How to see if local Administrator account's password is set by Group Policies in domain?

Tags: windows, administrator, active-directory, domain, group-policy

I want to check whether the local Administrator account's password is set centrally by group policies.

Currently, I know how to check whether the local Administrator account is renamed:

```
Local Policies > Security Options: "Accounts: Rename administrator account"
```

But what group policy setting sets the local Administrator account's password?

Furthermore, if set, where is the password stored?

Comment: Have you tried running rsop.msc?

Comment: @InterLinked - please elaborate.

Comment: Press WIN+R type "rsop.msc" and hit ENTER. Look through the policies until you find the one pertinent to what you are looking for.

Comment: @InterLinked - What is the difference between gpedit.msc and rsop.msc?

Comment: gpedit.msc is used to EDIT group policy, rsop.msc is used to VIEW the group policies applied to your user and/or computer account